# Filesmatch is not working in .htaccess file

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I have created a .htaccess file and trying to have a CAS login when the user goes to a url (ie: https://www.mycompany.com/users/forms/immigration.php)

I have created a filesmatch if the page begins with either imm or imp and ends in a .php, it should prompt a CAS login. I have used the FilesMatch tag and here the following code:

```
<FilesMatch "^(imm|imp)\.php$">
     Authtype CAS
     Require valid-user 
</FilesMatch>
```

Is there a different directive tag I should use?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to include `.*` after initial part to allow matching `immigration.php`:

```
<FilesMatch "^(imm|imp).*\.php$">
     Authtype CAS
     Require valid-user 
</FilesMatch>
```